# React and Flux: Handeling Aync calls

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a react component - a page where users can create an application. When they click create, I make an async call. If the async call is successful then I let the dispatcher know about the action. Otherwise, if I receive an error, I don't inform the dispatcher and render some error text instead.

Is this how others would go about handling such a scenario? I think this is the right approach, but there is a part of me that thinks that the dispatcher should be handling the async call. However, I'm not sure how I would inform the view that an error has occurred. I could re-render the view and pass the error as a prop, but this approach seems like it's adding too much complexity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was pointed to 2 other SO questions:

[How do you manage asynchronous Store operations with Flux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635964/how-do-you-manage-asynchronous-store-operations-with-flux)

[Should flux stores, or actions (or both) touch external services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630611/should-flux-stores-or-actions-or-both-touch-external-services)

In short, your action-creator can make the async request, then dispatch the appropriate action: FAILED-REQUEST or COMPLETE-ADD-APPLICATION

The FAILED-REQUEST action can update a store with the error, and your component can use that error.