# React-Native component listener is not receiving events on recurring update from the store

Tags: android, react-native

In my component, I've this code

```
  componentDidMount(){
       AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onUpdate);
  }
```

In my store, addChangeListener definition exist

```
  emitChange: function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },
```

"_onUpdate" on the component gets called just once when the Store emits Change. When promise is resolved after a few minutes, store does emit another change but the component wouldn't catch that event for some reason.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here in this thread. Appropriate design based on flux recommended practices.. [Is triggering an action in the store bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203081/is-triggering-an-action-in-the-store-bad-practice)