# How to resolve dependency between actions within a Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

My Store registers 2 actiontypes as follows:

```
Dispatcher.register(function (action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'loadCar':
            loadCar();
            break;
        case 'loadTyres':
            loadTyres();
            break;
    }
})
```

how can I assure, that `loadCar`is executed before `loadTyres`? Is there a way to *wait* for this depending method without having to execute `loadCar` everytime I want to just `loadTyres`?

Comment: Do you mean you want a `waitFor`: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html

Comment: I don't think that `waitFor` fits in here, as it only waits for *other* stores to update (which means it waits for all pending dispatches to being processed)

Comment: You could just have a state variable that tracks whether it has been loaded, or use a promise.

Comment: even with a promise I would have to call both methods, don't I...

Comment: `carpromise.then(loadTyres())` for example ...?

Comment: could you provide a complete example as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an untested pattern you might try.  You'll maybe need to start dispatching a `start loadcar`, `loadcar completed` for example to complete this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635964/how-do-you-manage-asynchronous-store-operations-with-flux)).

```
// pick your favorite Promise library
var Promise = require('bluebird'); 

Dispatcher.register(function (action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'loadCar':
            // need to be async here
            loadCar(action.carId).then(function(car) {
                // this eventually returns                      
            });
            break;
        case 'loadTyres':
            // need to be async here
            loadTyres(action.carId).then(function(tyres) {

            })
            break;
    }
})
```

You could also save the Promise object and cache it so that it is the "current"
car and then it wouldn't be reloaded (unless you remove it from the array).

```
var allCars = {};
function loadCar(id) {
    if(typeof allCars[id] === 'undefined') {
        allCars[id] = loadCarPromise(id);
    }
    return allCars[id];
}
```

You'll create a function that returns a Promise that will resolve with the specifics of the `car` data you're loading. You'll need to do whatever you would normally do there, but eventually call the `resolve` or `reject` callbacks to properly continue the Promise chain.

```
function loadCarPromise(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // do whatever you do to get
        // the car
        // when it's done, call resolve
        // or reject if there is a failure.
        // ex:
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/car/' + id,
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And finally, `loadTyres` would use `loadCar` internally and only resolve itself when the tyre data has been returned.

```
function loadTyres(carId) {
    // the car is always loaded first, then the tyres
    // but if using the cache, the car will be
    // returned immediately (although you won't need
    // to worry about that)
    return loadCar(carId).then(function(car) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // do something to load the tyres
            // with the car info that was returned
            resolve(/* tyres data */);          
        });
    });
}
```